# Hiding a control with css (wizard)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard-control

After defining 2 simple properties in my css to hide my controls it worked perfectly.
All my controls were in a table first, and when the page loaded they were invisble.
When i pressed on the button called "submit" all controls became visible. I assigned class="hide" on startup and in the button itself CssClass="show".

```
 .show
 {
   display:block;
 }
  .hide
 {
   display:none;
 }
```

But the problem is i needed a wizard control. So i placed all these controls into the wizard.
The wizard has 3 wizardsteps and the first one still has a table in it.

Everything works fine, i cannot seem to get the show function work anymore.

On startup the Wizard is hidden, if i would assign show (in the aspx.file) then the wizard shows up as it should.

But the problem is it does not seem to trigger the CssClass="..."  code line in my submit button anymore (.aspx.cs file)

```
   <asp:Wizard ID="WizardControl" runat="server" CssClass="hide" ActiveStepIndex="0"> 



   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       WizardControl.CssClass = "show";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by placing my Wizard into a div element.
And with the property visible/false i can toggle it on or off.